# adjusting the line width of the header with geometry fanchyhdr

Tags: header-footer, margins, incompatibility, fancyhdr, geometry

the line is longer than the width of the text, how do I adjust, knowing that the package needs fanchyhdr geometry?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{preambulo}
%Configuracao de pagina
\geometry{paperwidth=18cm,paperheight=24cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm}
\usepackage[a4,center,cam]{crop}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=TwoPageLeft, %SinglePage
  bookmarksopen=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=black,
  pdftitle={titulo},
  pdfauthor={R\'egis S. Santos}
}

\newcommand{\titulo}{Book}
\title{\titulo}
\author{R\'egis S. Santos}
\date{\the\year}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\frontmatter   %book
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter    %book

%texto
\chapter{Book}
\label{chap_Book}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}

and preambulo.sty

%Preambulo geral -2011
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,indentfirst}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{enumerate,multicol,subfigure,cancel,makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{wasysym,mathrsfs,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
%%força um \pagestyle{empty} em \part
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}
%********************************************************************
\everymath{\displaystyle}
%********************************************************************
% Configuracao de ambiente de teorema
% a numeracao do teorema depende da classe de documento
\usepackage{theorem}

\newcommand*{\teorema}[1][chapter]{
  \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[#1]
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
  \newtheorem{ex}{Exemplo}[#1]
  \newtheorem{exerc}{}[#1]
  \newtheorem{cor}[teo]{Corol\'ario}
  \newtheorem{lem}[teo]{Lema}
  \newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposi\c{c}\~ao}
  \newtheorem{axi}[teo]{Axioma}
  \newtheorem{fato}[teo]{Fato}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
  \newtheorem{defn}[teo]{Defini\c{c}\~ao}
}
%********************************************************************
% Configuracao de cabecalho personalizado
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand*{\BookHeader}[1]{%
  %%teoremas
  \teorema  %if book
  %%cabecalho e rodape
  \fancyhead{} % deleta a configuração atual para cabeçalho.
  %redefine para que apareça apenas o nº do capitulo.
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space##1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\space##1}}
  %evenside - lado par
  %oddside - lado impar
  \fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}  %capitulo do lado esquerdo na pag. par.
  \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark} %seção do lado direito na pag. impar.
  \fancyfoot{} % deleta a configuração atual para rodapé.
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}   %nº da pagina do lado direito e no rodapé.
  \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize{\titulo}}
  \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{R\'egis {\Large \smiley} \the\year}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{12.5pt} % cria espaço para a linha
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{} % exibe o cabeçalho e o rodapé
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % e a linha
  }
  \typeout{Using book class.}%
}%

\newcommand*{\ArticleHead}[1]{%
  %%teoremas
  \teorema[section] % if article
  %%cabecalho e rodape
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries\thepage}   %nº da pagina do lado direito
  \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize{\titulo}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{R\'egis {\Large \smiley} \the\year}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \typeout{Using article class.}%
}%

\newcommand*{\ReportHead}[1]{%
  %%teoremas
  \AfterPreamble{\teorema}  %if report
  %%cabecalho e rodape
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space##1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\space##1}}
  \fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\leftmark}  %capitulo do lado esquerdo
  \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\rightmark} %seção do lado direito
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries\thepage}   %nº da pagina do lado direito
  \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize{\titulo}}
  \fancyfoot[L]{R\'egis {\Large \smiley} \the\year}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{12.5pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \typeout{Using report class.}%
}%

\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\SetHeaders}[1]{%
    \@ifclassloaded{book}{\BookHeader{#1}%
    }{\@ifclassloaded{article}{\ArticleHead{#1}%
    }{\@ifclassloaded{report}{\ReportHead{#1}}{%
      \typeout{Error: Unsupported class: 'article' or 'report' or 'book' are suported.}
    }}}%
}%
\makeatother%

\SetHeaders{foo}%
%********************************************************************
% Ambiente para demonstração que coloca quadrado no final, usando \rule
% Nota: \rule{largura}{altura} produz um retagulo preto.
\newenvironment{dem}[1][Demonstração]{\textbf{#1:}\

}  {\hfill\rule{1ex}{1ex}}

% Ambiente para resolução de exercícios. Não juntar!
\newenvironment{sol}[1][Solução]{\uline{#1}:\

}  {\hfill $\Box$}  %O espaço provoca uma mudança de parágrafo no texto.
```

Comment: When compiling your not-so-MWE document, the `fancyhdr` line is just as **long** as `\textwidth`. Its **width** (`\headrulewidth`) is `0pt` (non-existent) on `plain` pages, and `0.5pt` on all other pages. What TeX distribution are you using? Some coding style suggestions: `lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm` is equivalent to `margin=3cm`. Your command `\SetHeaders` does not require an argument. So use `\newcommand*{\SetHeaders}{...}` dropping the `[1]` and call `\SetHeaders` (not `\SetHeaders{foo}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call **geometry** before `preambulo.sty`, so that **fancyhdr** will know about the correct text width.

Comment: You're right. I compiled the document on [ScribTeX](www.scibtex.com), so I just copied/pasted `preambulo.sty` into the document preamble *after* `geometry`, and also changed `\geometry{...}` to `\usepackage[...]{geometry}`.