# Question about changing the position of the footnote rule

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided

My question is after I redefine the length of footrule, the footrule doesn't change the position on even or odd page, it's always at the left side. Did I lost something or there's the other way to redefine it? sorry for updating late.

[image: footrule]

Comment: If you're using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set your page layout, you need to do that *before* setting the header/footer via [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). See [Adjusting the line width of the header with `geometry` and `fanchyhdr`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25579/5764).  Is this the case?

Comment: Do you want to change the length or the position of the rule?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can check if the page is even or odd and place the rule accordingly; here's an example illustrating this with the help of the `ifoddpage` package:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\normalsize BlahBlahBlahBlah\\BlahBlahBlahBlah}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage\hfill\else\fi\rule{2.5in}{\footrulewidth}\vskip\footruleskip}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!This is exactly I what I need!Thank you!