# How to extend the heading to the full text width?

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

How can I make the headings (with `fancyhdr`) extend to the full width of the text column?

The width of the text is larger than normal because it has been expanded using the `geometry` package. For this reason the right-aligned headings do not touch the right margin.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lhead{Left}
\chead{Center}
\rhead{Right}

\lipsum \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `geometry` before `fancyhdr`, that's all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [adjusting the line width of the header with `geometry` `fanchyhdr`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25579/5764)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard), the solution is to load `geometry` before `fancyhdr`; `fancyhdr` sets its default lenghts at load-time.

This is the fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % geometry is loaded first...

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % ...and then fancyhdr is loaded
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lhead{Left}
\chead{Center}
\rhead{Right}

\lipsum \lipsum
\end{document}
```